# How to skip a specific string when populating my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am populating a tableview from data that is received from a server.  The data is a list of user activities within a given timeframe.  One such activity is "Login".  I do not wish to populate my tableview with this string but I'm not sure how to skip it when populating my tableview.

Here is how I populate the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    @try{

        NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *action = [object valueForKey:@"theActionName"];

        if ([action isEqualtoString:@"Login"]) {

            return cell;
        }

        return cell;

    }@catch (NSException *ex) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried using `return cell` but as you probably know it gives me a blank cell when the table is displayed.  I'm sure there is a simple line of code for this but I came up blank with the search terms I used.  Could someone please enlighten me!  Thanks!

P.S. you may be thinking I am not putting anything in any of the cells but I pulled out a bunch of code to keep this short.

UPDATE:
Thanks for the heads up on "isEqualtoString:"  Everything worked fine with "isEqual" but I changed it given that I received so many suggestions to do so.  But this is not what I am asking.

To be more clear if I had an array containing the terms: view, view, login, view.  When my tableview was populated I would have 4 cells that said; view, view, login, view.  I simply want to ignore the term login so that I would have 3 cells that all said view.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you must first filter the dataSource then put that filtered result in another array and then use newFileteredDataSource, then you would not need to check any condition.

Comment: Don't use try catch for control flow in Cocoa. That's what all the error parameters in the method calls are for. Use those instead.

Comment: thanks @Abizern I will look into the error parameters.  I inherited some portions of this code from a previous developer so there is some details I need to work out like error control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many way to do this.

I Belive that `UITabelView` should display what its datasource (here datasource is `self.fetchedResultsController`) contains.

What you can do is create another `NSArray` from `self.fetchedResultsController` which does not contain this object.

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *newSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for(int i = 0; i < self.fetchedResultsController.count ; i++)
        {
            NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSString *action = [object valueForKey:@"theActionName"];

            if (![action isEqual:@"Login"])
            {
                [newSource addObject:action];
            }
        }

        [tableView reloadData];
```

Now use newSource instead of self.fetchedResultsController

You might think that using one more array is not good. But believe it it is far easier than using the same array with condition. You don't have to worry about that condition when you perform some operation with your `UITableView` like remove object by using indexpath.

Comment: CRDave, Let me just see if I understand your code right.  The point of the for loop is to populate the Array `*newSource`.  If I run into an `*action` which is not equal to "Login" then I populate the Array.  I think I'm right so far but I'm not sure what the function of `[tableView reload]` is?  Reload is self explanatory in nature but could you explain what is actually happening... has the table view been populated once then reloaded with the new array?

Comment: Well with two suggestions to filter the datasource then load it I will go that route.  I thought there would be simple command to just skip to the next item in the index path but apparently not.  Filtering the dataSource will be simple enough. Thanks for the suggestion CRDave and @Xman.

Comment: Sorry for that reloadData mistake.

Comment: The reason of not having command is very simple. UITableView should reflect datasource as it is. If you want to show part of it that filter it like we do commonly in database with select query to display part of data or create views.

Answer (score 1):

try using  `if ([action isEqualToString:@"Login"])`

Comment: isEqual will work perfect as isEqualToString. see : http://blog.bignerdranch.com/334-isequal-vs-isequaltostring/

Comment: @CRDave thanks for pointing that one out and providing a reference. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to compare strings you need to use this `isEqualToString` .

Change this line

```
if ([action isEqualToString:@"Login"]) {

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function to compare your input string and the given data variable.
They both are NSString objects so use :

```
if([action isEqualToString:@"Login"])
{
    //enter your code here
}
```

Comment: isEqual will work perfect as isEqualToString. see : http://blog.bignerdranch.com/334-isequal-vs-isequaltostring/

Answer (score 0):

@Ben : I am assuming that you have registered you cell through nib as you are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.
Make your tableview content as "Dynamic prototype" (You can see this in Attributes Inspector of table view) and change your table view cell style as custom (You can see this in Attributes Inspector of tableview cell).

Comment: yes everything has been set up as you describe using Storyboards.  The tableview populates correctly, I simply want to ignore the string "login" as the rows are populated.  For instance if I had an array with items: "view", "Login", "View", "View". My tableview will have 4 cells that say: view, login, view, view just like the array.  I want three cells that all say view....